# In My React Native Project, the metro bundler starts android to completion, but metro bundler never starts ios

Tags: react-native

I just updated my mac os x to Catalina 10.15.1, and I updated xcode to version 11.2.

Now I got the latest react-native version 0.61.4.

I generated my project:
`react-native init myProject`

After react native generated the skeleton of my project, I then went ahead to make sure that I could run my project in the ios and android emulators.

When I ran:
`react-native run-android`

android-studio builds the project successfully, and then immediately the metro bundler starts for android all the way to completion, and then displays the app that comes with the downloaded project skeleton in the android emulator.

However, when I run:
`react-native run-ios`

xcode builds the project successfully, and the ios emulator launches, and displays the white screen with the project title, but the metro bundler never starts for ios. And the ios emulator simply remains with the white screen and the project title for a long time.

I have the app displayed in the android emulator, but not in the ios emulator. And I am running this from mac os x Catalina 10.15.1 and Xcode 11.2, and I am using react-native version 0.61.4. Can someone please provide me with some assistance on this?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue.

The issue had to do with the version of nodejs that I had running on my mac os x. The nodejs version I was using 12.13.0. So I downgraded to **nodejs version 10.17.0**.

And after running `react-native` commands for both `run-ios` and `run-android`, and were both successful, started the metro bundler, and loaded both applications within each emulator successfully.

My react-native, xcode, and mac os x versions all remained the same. The only thing I changed was the nodejs version.